# How to .load content into the start of a webpage?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently hacking a pretty wonky website where I need to insert a DOCTYPE in the beginning of each page with jQuery. I'm aware of jQuery's load-method, however it requires a HTML tag of some sorts.

How do I insert my DOCTYPE to the beginning of the page, is there a way to address the DOM-root of the document?

```
$([beginning-of-document]).load('doctype.html');
```

Comment: Would loading the DOCTYPE after the page loads serve any purpose? I don't think it would be useful to load the DOCTYPE after the browser has started rendering the page. You might consider doing it via server side

Comment: I think you're right - it has to be the first thing that loads. Is this something you can't do with JS?

Comment: Nope. You'd need server side for this kind of thing.

Comment: +1: A very interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that the `doctype` property is read only.

perhaps a trick would be to

- extract the whole document
- replace the document
- rewrite the whole document

(no guarantees)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently hacking a pretty wonky
>   website where I need to insert a
>   DOCTYPE in the beginning of each page
>   with jQuery.

Yes, you can do that using jquery .load () and load a HTML page or parts of it in a specified location, say e.g `<div id ="your_id_forbeginning"> </div>`

> How do I insert my DOCTYPE to the
>   beginning of the page, is there a way
>   to address the DOM-root of the
>   document?

Yes, `document.body` will get your job done.

But if you call the .load() on document.body, then the DOCTYPE will replace the whole body, which isn't what you want.

So, before calling load(), you need to add a `<div id="something">` to your body at the beginning(which should be easy), and then call the load() for that `<div>.`